# Authentication failures when using paramiko with an ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com public certificate

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, openssh

I am working with an internal system that when asking for SSH keys, it returns three files:

- id_rsa (presumably the private key)
- id_rsa.pub (presumably the public key)
- id_rsa-cert (A [public key certificate](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.certkeys)?)

The -cert file begins with `ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com` which leads me to believe it is indeed the above linked public key although most sources speak of the -cert.pub extension.

If I connect to the machine using the SSH agent, it seems that everything's in working order, and the `-cert` file is recognized as "type 4":

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.176.34.90 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.176.34.90 [10.176.34.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /tmp/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /tmp/id_rsa-cert type 4
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.176.34.90:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:dcU1jNy+H6haaVGW/O3KKyeQljaFII4B8uztw//VxLM
debug1: Host '10.176.34.90' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/wonderb0lt/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /tmp/id_rsa RSA SHA256:kmgmx/E7PzCEHvzSPIooMKpEHqmmCDMoRLMAF3JRvug explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /tmp/id_rsa RSA-CERT SHA256:kmgmx/E7PzCEHvzSPIooMKpEHqmmCDMoRLMAF3JRvug explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /tmp/id_rsa RSA SHA256:kmgmx/E7PzCEHvzSPIooMKpEHqmmCDMoRLMAF3JRvug explicit agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /tmp/id_rsa RSA-CERT SHA256:kmgmx/E7PzCEHvzSPIooMKpEHqmmCDMoRLMAF3JRvug explicit
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: /tmp/id_rsa RSA-CERT SHA256:kmgmx/E7PzCEHvzSPIooMKpEHqmmCDMoRLMAF3JRvug explicit
debug2: sign_and_send_pubkey: using private key "/tmp/id_rsa" for certificate
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

However, when I try to do a similar connection attempt in paramiko with the following code:

```py
pkey = RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/tmp/kx/id_rsa')
pkey.load_certificate('/tmp/kx/id_rsa-cert')
c = SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
c.connect(hostname='10.176.33.64', username='ec2-user', pkey=pkey, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
print(c.exec_command('ls -l'))
```

I am greeted with an authentication exception:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x6f9d3a60
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.9.2
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.4)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange possibilities ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos: curve25519-sha256, curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group16-sha512, diffie-hellman-group18-sha512, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1, diffie-hellman-group14-sha256, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server key: ssh-rsa, rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com, aes128-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes256-cbc, blowfish-cbc, cast128-cbc, 3des-cbc
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com, aes128-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes256-cbc, blowfish-cbc, cast128-cbc, 3des-cbc
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client mac: umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server mac: umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex follows: False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange agreements ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey: ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== End of kex handshake ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Got EXT_INFO: {'server-sig-algs': b'rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512'}
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-ed25519 host key for 10.176.33.64: b'b0878c9bc616a0c5fa69ee252730bc17'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH key b'00f98d495396b7cdad1fa25c87e3f694'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Finalizing pubkey algorithm for key of type 'ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Our pubkey algorithm list: ['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa']
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Server-side algorithm list: ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512']
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Agreed upon 'rsa-sha2-512' pubkey algorithm
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
```

I am out of ideas. I've tried to switch out the `pkey` parameter for `key_filename` both referring to the `-cert` file as well as the private key, and I've also renamed the `id_rsa-cert` file to `id_rsa-cert.pub` in my desperation, all to no avail.

That the connection per SSH client works leads me to believe I'm using Paramiko wrong somehow. I'm aware of the issue with [Paramiko >=2.9.0](https://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html) and the server-sig-algs, but I don't think that's the issue. If I exclude the algorithms as the note suggests, but that just leads to another exception that no algorithm could be agreed upon - I'm fairly certain our servers are built just to accept these specific key types.

Comment: Actually, I mentioned the solution that the linked question gives in my text, which didn't work, so thanks for closing anyway.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice. But I gave you *days* to object that and *you never responded*.

Comment: Anyway, did you try to sable just the `rsa-sha2-512`? + Can you authenticate with a plain private key, instead of the certificate?